# No notification in my inbox for comments

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

I'm facing a problem in the new SO display update. I'm not getting any notifications in my inbox for the Comment posted by other users for my Question

Reference Link : [Creating folder in the local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467921/creating-folder-in-the-local-file-system#)

[image]

Is it working correctly or Fault is my side ?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed the same behavior, but when I checked later, the notification was there; it just appeared silently.

Comment: @3ventic - Yes but some  times it is not even prompted silently also

Comment: That's a bug in the inbox notifications. Hopefully just a temporary glitch.

Comment: I guess it's silly to revive this topic based on the problem, but just yesterday this started happening to me.